# npm install not creating the json file

Tags: json, node.js

I updated npm installed node express,even though it is not creating the jason file. can any one please let me know how to fix this.

ramesh@ramesh-PC MINGW32 ~
$ npm init
This utility will walk you through creating a package.json file.
It only covers the most common items, and tries to guess sane defaults.

See `npm help json` for definitive documentation on these fields
and exactly what they do.

Use `npm install <pkg> --save` afterwards to install a package and
save it as a dependency in the package.json file.

Press ^C at any time to quit.
name: (ramesh)

ramesh@ramesh-PC MINGW32 ~

Comment: what you want to achieve ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First initialize your project. Assuming your project lives in directory "sample" then:

```
cd sample
npm init // This will ask a bunch of questions. you can mostly just hit "enter". it will create the package.json file for you
npm i express --save
```

Comment: by giving npm init it is just giving me the below output instead of asking questions.$ npm init
This utility will walk you through creating a package.json file.
It only covers the most common items, and tries to guess sane defaults.

See `npm help json` for definitive documentation on these fields
and exactly what they do.

Use `npm install <pkg> --save` afterwards to install a package and
save it as a dependency in the package.json file.

Press ^C at any time to quit.
name: (ramesh)
ramesh@ramesh-PC MINGW32 /

Comment: it is just coming out without creating any json file

Comment: Seriously?  Are you getting any permission errors when you say yes at the last step of `npm init`? What happens when you do `less package.json` as a last command? Does it say `package.json: No such file or directory`?

Comment: what is the out come of npm init I mentioned in the above post. please have a look on my first post.Still problem is not resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Try not to make any space between words in your project folder name. For instance, instead of "My Portfolio" write it like "MyPortfolio". This worked for me and created json file automatically in my project folder.

Answer (score 0):

using `npm init` you can create `package.json`

Comment: by giving npm init it is just giving me the below output instead of asking questions.$ npm init
This utility will walk you through creating a package.json file.
It only covers the most common items, and tries to guess sane defaults.

See `npm help json` for definitive documentation on these fields
and exactly what they do.

Use `npm install <pkg> --save` afterwards to install a package and
save it as a dependency in the package.json file.

Press ^C at any time to quit.
name: (ramesh)
ramesh@ramesh-PC MINGW32 /  it is not creating jason file. not asking any questions.

Comment: it is just coming out without creating any json file

Answer (score 0):

To clarify a bit on the previous answers, `npm install <package-name>` and `npm install <package-name> --save` may fail if you try to run them from a directory that does not have an npm `package.json` file.

You might type something like `npm install crud --save` and get some confusing output like this:

```
npm install crud
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/youruser/package.json'
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/youruser/package.json'
npm WARN youruser No description
npm WARN youruser No repository field.
npm WARN youruser No README data
npm WARN youruser No license field.

+ crud@0.0.28
```

That's not a very helpful error message -- the level is only "warn", and that last line makes it appear that the requested package got installed somewhere.  But if you look in your directory, *you will see it remains empty*.  The explanation of this "riddle" is that some package installers (like PHP's composer) will initialize a project and download the package, others (like Python's pip or npm) do not, so you have to initialize the directory and install packages separately.

Run `npm init` and answer some basic questions about your project, or copy a viable `package.json` file that follows the format below:

```
{
  "name": "my-great-node-project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {

  }
}
```

Be careful with the package name!  The name cannot match the name of a package you trying to install.

Once the directory has been initialize, you should be able to run your `npm install <package-name> --save` command and have the package installed into the `node_modules` directory and have your `package.json` file updated.